# Jquery .post() with php

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand how the `$.post()` method works in Jquery WITHOUT using `$.ajax` as I've seen in a video tutorial on php acadamy but the author made it really confusing by naming his variables the same thing.

Overall this is what I plan to do:

The script is suppose to be a contact script: The user creates individual lines of the contract which are saved in a multidimensional `object/array` containing a key and the term, when they finalize the contract (by clicking a button), the `key/term array/object` is sent to a PHP script which saves it in a database and then send it's it back to the page to be displayed properly parsed.

The part I'm stuck at is getting the object to the php script and getting a response from the php script to (ultimately display) back to the jquery.

```
    $('#createbtn').click(function() {
    $.each(terms_array,function(key, value) {
        var toAdd = value;
        $.post('contract_handler.php',{toAdd:toAdd}, function(data){
            $('contractlist').append(data);
        });

    });

});
```

I'm not sure what is happening in  **{toAdd:toAdd}**.

I know one of them is the variable in the jquery. Is the other one the variable name of the variable in PHP? Is it hte variable thats supposed to be passed back?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['toAdd']))
    $x = $_POST['toAdd']
    //do database saving and parsing and what not...
    /* NOW HOW DO I GET X BACK TO THE JQUERY AS 'data' SO IT CAN DISPLAY IT??? /*
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to *output* the value, e.g. with `echo`:

```
echo $x;
```

> I'm not sure what is happening in {toAdd:toAdd}. I know one of them is the variable in the jquery. Is the other one the variable name of the variable in PHP?

`{toAdd:toAdd}` is an object literal that creates an object with a property `toAdd` and the value of the variable `toAdd`. jQuery takes this object, encodes the data and sends it to the server. If you are doing a GET request, the data will be added to the query string of the URL. In a POST request, the data will be encoded in the same way, but sent in the body of the request.
So, assuming `toAdd` is `42`, then the encoded data will look like this:

```
toAdd=42
```

In PHP you can then either access the data with `$_GET['toAdd']` or `$_POST['toAdd']`, depending on the method you used.

Answer (score 1):

`{toAdd:toAdd}` is the data that is passed to the url.

Where the first part is the parameter name, second part is the value, here it is a variable so the value of the variable is passed.

Also in the said case the value of the toAdd variable is the same as the value of the `value` parameter of the each handler method, so it can be written as

```
$.each(terms_array,function(key, value) {
    $.post('contract_handler.php',{toAdd: value}, function(data){
        $('contractlist').append(data);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much difference between `$.post()` and `$.ajax()`. `$.post()` and `$.get()` are just shortcuts for sending a basic POST and GET request. Also, in your example, you probably want to be using `value` for your POST data to the server.

```
$.post('contract_handler.php', {toAdd: value}, function (data) {
    $('contractlist').append(data);
});
```

is the same as

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'contract_handler.php',
    data : {
        toAdd: value
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('contractlist').append(data);
    }
});
```

The same goes for `$.get()`. If you only need to pass data and only want a success callback, `$.post()` is for you. If you require more configuration, switch to `$.ajax()`.

From what you provided, you need to echo out `$x` in your php script so that it will be returned in your data variable. With higher programming practices in mind, I would definitely recommend JSON Encoding your return data.

```
echo JSON_encode($x);
```

This allows you to pass more specific data back with your return data, and allow you to keep any DOM manipulation in javascript. If I'm not in a RESTful environment like your example suggests, I would send my data back in a wrapper to give myself some success statuses and server messages

```
$return = array(
    status  : 1,
    message : 'Successfully added',
    data    : $x
);
echo JSON_encode($return);
```

This way, in your success callback, you can check to make sure there weren't any errors, and if there were, you already have the server message ready to display.

```
$.post('contract_handler.php', {toAdd: value}, function (response) {
    if (response.status=== 1) {
        // Server was successful, now do your thing
        $('contractlist').append(data.data);
    }
    else {
        // Server encountered an error, alert the user
        /*
            UI Error Handling Here
         */

        // Throw console error for debugging while in development
        console.error("Error " + response.status + ": " + response.message");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you out.